# DataFrame of means of top N most correlated columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` where each column represents a time series of returns.  I want to create a new dataframe `df2` with columns that corresponds to each of the columns in `df1` where the column in `df2` is defined to be the average of the top 5 most correlated columns in `df1`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_letters

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 10).round(2),
                   columns=list(ascii_letters[26:36]))

print df1.head()

      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
0 -2.13 -1.27 -1.97 -2.26 -0.35 -0.03  0.32  0.35  0.72  0.77
1 -0.61  0.35 -0.35 -0.42 -0.91 -0.14  0.75 -1.50  0.61  0.40
2 -0.96  1.49 -0.35 -1.47  1.06  1.06  0.59  0.30 -0.77  0.83
3  1.49  0.26 -0.90  0.38 -0.52  0.05  0.95 -1.03  0.95  0.73
4  1.24  0.16 -1.34  0.16  1.26  0.78  1.34 -1.64 -0.20  0.13
```

I expect the `head` of the resulting dataframe rounded to 2 places to look like:

```
      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
0 -0.78 -0.70 -0.53 -0.45 -0.99 -0.10 -0.47 -0.86 -0.31 -0.64
1 -0.49 -0.11 -0.45 -0.03 -0.04  0.10 -0.26  0.11 -0.06 -0.10
2  0.03  0.13  0.54  0.33 -0.13  0.27  0.22  0.32  0.41  0.27
3 -0.22  0.13  0.19  0.58  0.63  0.24  0.34  0.51  0.32  0.22
4 -0.04  0.31  0.23  0.52  0.43  0.24  0.07  0.31  0.73  0.43
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each column in the correlation matrix, take the six largest and ignore the first one (i.e. 100% correlated with itself).  Use a dictionary comprehension to do this for each column.

Use another dictionary comprehension to located this columns in `df1` and take their mean.  Create a dataframe from the result, and reorder the columns to match those of df1 by appending `[df1.columns]`.

```
corr = df1.corr()
most_correlated_cols = {col: corr[col].nlargest(6)[1:].index
                        for col in corr}

df2 = pd.DataFrame({col: df1.loc[:, most_correlated_cols[col]].mean(axis=1) 
                    for col in df1})[df1.columns]

>>> df2.head()
       A      B      C      D      E      F      G      H      I      J
0 -0.782 -0.698 -0.526 -0.452 -0.994 -0.102 -0.472 -0.856 -0.310 -0.638
1 -0.486 -0.106 -0.454 -0.032 -0.042  0.100 -0.258  0.108 -0.064 -0.102
2  0.026  0.132  0.544  0.330 -0.130  0.272  0.224  0.320  0.414  0.274
3 -0.224  0.128  0.186  0.582  0.626  0.242  0.344  0.506  0.318  0.224
4 -0.044  0.310  0.230  0.518  0.428  0.238  0.068  0.306  0.734  0.432

%%timeit
corr = df1.corr()
most_correlated_cols = {
   col: corr[col].nlargest(6)[1:].index
   for col in corr}
df2 = pd.DataFrame({col: df1.loc[:, most_correlated_cols[col]].mean(axis=1) 
                    for col in df1})[df1.columns]
100 loops, best of 3: 10 ms per loop

%%timeit
corr = df1.corr()
df2 = corr.apply(argsort).head(5).apply(lambda x: avg_of(x, df1))
100 loops, best of 3: 16 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander.  I'm currently running this with 20 years of monthly observations taking 12 month rolling windows.  The number of securities range from ~20k 20 years ago to ~45k more recently.  If the efficiency improvement scales, that will be a huge savings.

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_letters

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 10).round(2),
                   columns=list(ascii_letters[26:36]))
```

#### Solution

```
corr = df.corr()

# I don't want a securities correlation with itself to be included.
# Because `corr` is symmetrical, I can assume that a series' name will be in its index.
def remove_self(x):
    return x.loc[x.index != x.name]

# This builds utilizes `remove_self` then sorts by correlation
# and returns the index.
def argsort(x):
    return pd.Series(remove_self(x).sort_values(ascending=False).index)

# This reaches into `df` and gets all columns identified in x
# then takes the mean.
def avg_of(x, df):
    return df.loc[:, x].mean(axis=1)

# Putting it all together.
df2 = corr.apply(argsort).head(5).apply(lambda x: avg_of(x, df))

print df2.round(2).head()

      A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
0 -0.78 -0.70 -0.53 -0.45 -0.99 -0.10 -0.47 -0.86 -0.31 -0.64
1 -0.49 -0.11 -0.45 -0.03 -0.04  0.10 -0.26  0.11 -0.06 -0.10
2  0.03  0.13  0.54  0.33 -0.13  0.27  0.22  0.32  0.41  0.27
3 -0.22  0.13  0.19  0.58  0.63  0.24  0.34  0.51  0.32  0.22
4 -0.04  0.31  0.23  0.52  0.43  0.24  0.07  0.31  0.73  0.43
```